# If $2 \cdot log_e{(x -2y)} = log_e{y} + log_e{x}$, then find the numerical value of $\frac{x}{y}$

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

If $2 \cdot log_e{(x -2y)} = log_e{y} + log_e{x}$, then find the numerical value of $\frac{x}{y}$

My try:

> $2 \cdot log_e{(x -2y)} = log_e{y} + log_e{x}$
>
> $log_e{(x-2y)^2} = log_e{xy}$
>
> $(x - 2y)^2 = xy$

But expanding the LHS doesn't give the result. What should I do further?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint :

$$2 \cdot \ln(x -2y) = \ln y + \ln x\Rightarrow \ln(x-2y)-\ln y=\ln x-\ln (x-2y)$$

i.e., $$\log \bigg(\frac{x-2y}{y}\bigg)=\log\bigg(\frac{x}{x-2y}\bigg)$$

i.e.,

$$\dfrac{x}{y}-2=\dfrac{1}{1-2\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)}$$
Can you complete this...?

Comment: what's the difference between this and that I wrote?

Comment: I have added one more step... can you complete that now?

Comment: There is a "huge" error in this solution. You missed on the 2 in the first step.

Comment: @Sid : I do not see what the error is... I am not missing any $2$.. Can you be more precise?

Comment: I am sorry, I may have misread it. It took me a little long to see what you did.

Comment: @Sid : it is alright :)

Answer (score 4):

*Hint*: Let $z = \frac xy$, dividing your last equation by $y^2$ (note that $y > 0$, as $\log y$ is defined), we get
$$ \frac xy = \left(\frac xy - 2\right)^2 \iff z = (z-2)^2 $$
Now solve for $z$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asked to calculate $\left(\frac {x}{y} \right) $ start with that and assume it to $t$.

Then, $2 \cdot log_e{(x -2y)} = log_e{y} + log_e{x}$ becomes

$2 \cdot log_e{(ty -2y)} = log_e{y} + log_e{ty}$

$\implies$${y^2}{{(t-2)}^2}=ty^2$

$\implies$${t^2}-4t+4=t$

$\implies$$t^2-5t+4=0$

$\implies$$(t-4)(t-1)=0$